# JLabel does not show the image specified in the table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlabel

I built a program with a JLabel and a JTable like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBXEL.png. I would like that when I click on a row in the table, the JLabel would show the image specified in the "Path" column.

I have already tried this code, but it does not work.

```
try{
    int row = table.getSelectedRow();
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(table.getValueAt(row, 1).toString()));
    //JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource(table.getValueAt(row, 1).toString()))));
    label.setBounds(313, 10, 762, 501);
    panel.add(label);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Where is the error?

Comment: There can be several problems. First one: Does the toString() method return the actual path or an object reference? Second one: you should not place Components manually with a null-Layout and setBound(). This can cause several problems. Third one: Is the path you retrieve from the table exactly the absolute path to the picture. Fourth one could be, is youi label definitly on the right place? There are too many factors. Please provide more code, results and maybe the current Layout

Comment: Add the label to the panel when you create the panel. Then when you select a row in the table just change the Icon of the label.

Comment: and: __never-ever__ do any manual sizing or locating, that's the exclusive task of a suitable layoutManager

Comment: @kleopatra I'm a newbie, I haven't figured out how to make the layout managers work yet, so I size the interfaces by hand.

Comment: @camickr Thanks, I put "setBounds" and "panel.add" in the right place.
With my code I just get an error "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 10"

Comment: @John  put "setBounds" and "panel.add" in the right place. Yes, the path given in the table is absolute. I'm not saying it's the best solution, but I can't think of anything better.

Comment: newbie or old hand - what you are doing is __wrong__ (in several aspects as the comments pointed out) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
        String imageName = table.getValueAt(row, 1).toString();
        ImageIcon filePath = new ImageIcon("Data/Screenshot/" + imageName);
        label.setIcon(filePath);
    }
});
```

Edit: removed `Image img = filePath.getImage();` and replaced `table.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {` with `table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {`

Thanks @weisj

Comment: Why are you calling getImage and immediately afterwards creating a new ImageIcon. Notably your solution doesn’t work when navigating the table using the keyboard. Instead of listening for mouse clicks add a listener to the tables SelectionModel.

Comment: @weisj You're right, I' ve fixed that. Thank you.

Comment: @kleopatra I fixed it. I forgot to remove "Override"